# SELECT higher priority row and return it value, grouping by type

Tags: sql, group-by, mariadb

I needs to `SELECT` a column based on `ORDER BY` and using also `GROUP BY`.

For instance, I have the following data:

```
id | type | value | priority
-    A      1       100
-    A      2       0
-    B      3       0
-    B      4       100
```

I need `GROUP BY type`, `SELECT value` considering `ORDER BY priority DESC`. In this case, the output will be:

```
type | value
A    | 1
B    | 4
```

Currently I can select the `MIN()` or `MAX()` values reported by `value`, for instance:

```
SELECT MAX(value) ... GROUP BY type
```

But it will returns wrong:

```
type | value
A    | 2
B    | 4
```

What I need is something like:

```
SELECT (value ORDER BY priority DESC) ... GROUP BY type
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution using `GROUP_CONCAT()` that supports your own scope `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DB's version is 10.2+, then consider using Analytic functions such as `ROW_NUMBER()` in which `PARTITION BY type` is used to GROUP BY type column, and filter out the returning values from the function equal to one :

```
WITH t2 AS
(
 SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY priority DESC) AS rn
   FROM t --> your original table
)   
SELECT type,value
  FROM t2
 WHERE rn = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=386274b1754165904275c8c9a3e243e3)</kbd>